# in Python can I use getElementsByTagName but preserve nested structure?

Tags: python, xml, getelementsbytagname

I am trying to merge several .xml files into one, which is working pretty good except an issue I run into with a nested tag.
I use a python script which does the following: read all .xml files in directory, extract all elements of certain tags (using getElementsByTagName) and put it in separate lists, then store these lists in 1 mergefile. I run into problems with nested tags.
So for example:

```
File1.xml:
<SomeTag>
  <content>Text1</content>
</SomeTag>
<OtherTag>
  <value>Val1</value>
</OtherTag>
```

is merged with:

```
File2.xml:
<SomeTag>
  <content>Text2</content>
</SomeTag>
<OtherTag>
  <OtherTag>
    <value>Val2</value>
    <element>Elem1</element>
  </OtherTag>
</OtherTag>
```

I was hoping to get:

```
<SomeTag>                                #container tag created in script
  <content>Text1</content>
  <content>Text2</content>
</SomeTag>
<OtherTag>                               #container tag created in script
  <value>Val1</value>
  <OtherTag>
    <value>Val2</value>
    <element>Elem1</element>
  </OtherTag>
</OtherTag>
```

But what I do get is:

```
<SomeTag>                                #container tag created in script
  <content>Text1</content>
  <content>Text2</content>
</SomeTag>
<OtherTag>                               #container tag created in script
  <OtherTag>
  </OtherTag>
  <OtherTag>
    <value>Val1</value>
    <value>Val2</value>
    <element>Elem1</element>
  </OtherTag>
</OtherTag>
```

I guess what I want is that getElementsByTagName only reads the 1st order depth, not recursively through the whole (Element)Tree xml structure.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: `OtherTag` in `OtherTag`, means both have same tag name ?

Comment: yes indeed Lafada. That's where I run into problems

Comment: Then problem with your xml, or you have to change logic. Traverse each node, and if `node == OtherTag` append, dont process child of `OtherTag`

Comment: thanks Lafada, can this be done with getElementsByTagName, or do I need to use another function?

Comment: `getElementByTagName` will return all node with `OtherTag` which include inner child also. You have to start from root node and check each child, if child tag name is `OtherTag` then add it and process next child not check for child of `OtherTag`.

Comment: I might be submit solution soon, busy with some other work now :)

Answer (score 0):

As Lagada mentioned, getElementsByTagName will get you *all* of the element of a given type, including nested ones. You can walk the tree yourself and just not descend further within the ones you've already got; but perhaps it would be easier to just get them all with getElementsByTagName, and then iterate through them, and discard any which have an ancestor of the same type (those, of course, are the nested ones). Then process the rest.